# Injections of Direct Sums

Tags: group-theory

Let A and B be subgroups of an abelian group G so that the map $A \oplus B \rightarrow G$ sending (a,b) to a-b has kernel $A \cap B$.  I would like to show that there is an injective map from $A \oplus B$ to $G \oplus (A \cap B)$.  What additional hypotheses do I need to make this true?

Comment: To be slightly more precise, the kernel is not $A\cap B$ (which is contained in $G$, not in $G\oplus G$), it is isomorphic to $A\cap B$ via $x\longmapsto (x,x)$.

Comment: I guess it is all about *Abelian groups*, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the group is abelian!  Sorry I forgot to specify.

Comment: You can't decide $\,A\oplus B\,$ within $\,A\,$ unless $\,A\cap B=\{0\}\,$ , or unless you mean the *external* direct product of $\,A,B\,$...so which one is it?